# Recruiters are very strongly encouraging me to be a full time employee instead of a contractor. What is their motivation?

Tags: recruitment, contractors, fulltime, consulting

I've been working with some 3rd party recruiters to find my next job.  Originally, they were looking for full time positions for me.  But in the process of my job search I decided I'd like to try to be a consultant/contractor for the first time in my life.  I've been in the work force for about 10 years now.

The recruiters seem to be very strongly against this move.  They've been telling me things like it'll make it very difficult to go back to full time positions if I change my mind later because I'll be considered a hired mercenary and that I'll be unreliable.  They say I'll have to work on the same things I already know and won't be able to learn new things on the job because people hire consultants when they need someone to hit the ground running, not as an investment.  They're saying lots of other things to dissuade me.

Now, all of this advice may be valid, but I wonder if there's an ulterior motive behind their advice.  Something like they'll get paid much more if they hire me as a full time employee than they would as a contractor?

I'd *like* to believe that they have my best interest at heart, but I can't help and feel like there's some angle I'm not seeing here.  Is their advice biased? If so, why?

Answer (score 7):

This depends heavily on your country and industry.

Generally speaking, recruiters are paid on commission.  That means, they get paid a percentage of your salary when they place you in a job*.

It may be that, in your case, they get paid a *lower* amount for placing a contractor than they do for a Full Time Employee.

You should do what you think is best for yourself - not what's best for them.

Personally, I've never heard of anyone having a problem switching between contracting and full-time.

My advice? If you really want to start contracting, find a new agency - preferably one which specialises in the way you want to work.

*It can be more complicated than that - sometimes they're paid a flat fee + a percentage, sometimes a percentage after you've been there X months etc.

Comment: +1, the recruiter is unlikely to care about you beyond the money they receive from your placement.

Answer (score 5):

Never, ever assume that recruiters have your best interest at heart, because except in very rare circumstances, they simply don't.  Recruiters get paid by commission, and only if they complete a sale (i.e. if they find you a job)

Be very aware that recruiters are not known for their honesty or their integrity, so don't trust them any more than you would trust a used car salesman.  They will tell you anything to get you to take the job.

If they only have contract jobs, they will tell you contract jobs are the best, and how you'll make more money, etc.  If they want to place you for a permanent job, they will tell you about long-term career prospects, stability, benefits, etc.

Usually there are more permanent jobs going than contract jobs, and so most recruiters will try to sell you a permanent job.  Don't let them sway you; do your own research and make your own decisions.

Comment: I would say recruiters get paid for finding "anyone" a job, so it doesn't have to be you.

Comment: @JeffO Yes but the more likely they think you are to get a job, the harder they will push for it.  It is also why they will actively discourage you from trying to progress your career or apply for a job they're not 100% sure you'll get -- they don't want you to take chances.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would look into doing what's right/best for you, and not what's the 'best' for the company!

Also, if the contracting job doesn't work well/fails, their 'successful' job allocations would fall, **lowering their statistics**.

the recruiters will be getting paid from the companies to 'get us employees', and so if you go off and do your own thing, they'll lose someone that could possibly be put into a company and be paid by them (they'll be losing revenue by not 'selling' you to the company). my general advise is that if you can get work from being a contractor, then do it. Otherwise, just stick tight!

Answer (score 0):

The most difficult part of being a recruiter is finding available jobs willing to pay the extra commission. There are some skill sets that are harder to find good candidates.

This particular recruiter may have more full-time positions to fill than contract positions. If they have both types of positions available, they get paid to fill both of them, so they shouldn't care which one any particular person gets placed. Again, it could be that your particular skill set has more full-time positions available.

Personally, I would think it is more difficult for those working full-time to switch to being a consultant/contractor than the other way around. Most people are use to the consistent pay check and don't like the risk of frequently changing jobs. It is possible your skills can get more focused (or isolated) as well as your industry experience.